# Monero Research Lab - Talent Acquisition. Whom would/do they want?

Tags: development, monero-research-lab, cryptography

The MRL, to my knowledge, is made up of four anonymous/pseudonymous academics, who primarily specialize in mathematics (mathematical sciences and algebraic geometry).  Are there other specialties that would be useful to the MRL now?  Are just mathematicians needed?  Are there tentative plans for work/research that may more specifically require cryptographers or computer scientists of particular disciplines?

Those follow-up questions are rhetorical, of course.  But I'm asking about "now" on purpose (say, in the first five or so years of the project).  This question would be too general and open-ended to ask what attributes an aspiring MRL member might possess.  Anyone could provide a "good enough" answer to that general question.

What I'm getting at is, for example, I'd like to know (and I especially want others who are more highly-skilled than me to know) what a fly on the wall would hear if that fly were in the room with an MRL researcher as he/she thinks out loud and says, "I would like to complete this research and get on to several other Monero research projects.  If only I had the assistance of some individual who _________________."

I don't mean to speculate.  There may be very few people who actually have specific insights that may enable them to answer this question.  In truth, I'm trying to ask about something way, way above my pay grade (well, well outside my area of expertise), in hopes that an individual with a suitable skill set will come across it and want to contribute (plus it's very interesting and I'm super curious).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that anyone who has the abilities and intent to do formal research on crypto/monero related subjects would be welcomed. Of course, this does not mean "limited abilities" and "wishy washy intent". I think we can all apply some common sense to this. However, I don't think there is any particular requirement of academic specialization. If you do, you're in, as in most open source and free software. You might have to show your worth first though, as in most open source and free software.

The legend says you should contact the "Fluffy Pony" if you're interested in becoming part of the MRL, and strange and magical things may happen from there.